# PHPMailer not working when function is within and included file

Tags: phpmailer

Something is mighty odd. I created a basic test file with the code from PHPMailer.

```
# Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require 'includes/PHPMailer/Exception.php';

function sendCampaignEmail ($email, $firstname, $lastname)
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Create a new PHPMailer instance. Passing `true` enables exceptions.
    try {
        //Server settings
        # $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;       // Enable verbose debug output.  SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
        # $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT;       // SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;       // SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'myhostxxxx.co.uk';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'oobaclub@xxxxxxxxx.co.uk';         // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxmyEmailPasswordxxxxx';        // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('myfromemail.co.uk', 'My Name');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $firstname . ' ' . $lastname);    // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('myfromemail.co.uk', 'My Name');

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'Dear ' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname . '<br/><br/>This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo '<br/>Message has been sent to ' . $email . ' (' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname . ')';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
    }


$names= array();

$id=0;

$names[$id]['email'] = "atestemail@gmail.com";
$names[$id]['first_name'] = "Bob";
$names[$id]['last_name'] = "gMail"; $id++;

$names[$id]['email'] = "anothertest@testingmyemail.co.uk";
$names[$id]['first_name'] = "Sid";
$names[$id]['last_name'] = "Smith"; $id++;



$count=0;
while ($count < count($names))
    {
    sendCampaignEmail ($names[$count]['email'], $names[$count]['first_name'], $names[$count]['last_name']);
    $count++;
    }
```

THIS CODE ABOVE WORKS FINE.

So... Then, I took the function and put it into an Included file (where all my functions are: "globalfunctions.php").... And now it says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found"

So, now, at the top of my index.php, I have:

```
## PHP MAILER - # Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once 'includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require_once 'includes/PHPMailer/Exception.php';

require_once 'includes/connect.php';
require_once 'includes/globalfunctions.php';
```

I am confused as everything else works. All my other functions work. I thought namespaces were global... But, I tried adding the "use" code into the function... but, as expected, that didn't work either....

I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP `use` declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) are local aliases that apply **only** to the file they appear in. You have to add a `use` statement in **every** file that uses that class; you can't put all your declares in one file and then include it from somewhere else.

Now might be a good time to learn how to use composer as it takes care of a lot of this.

Comment: Just to be clear on this. I removed the USE and the INCLUDE code from index.php file and added it to the top of my include file (globalfunctions.php)... i.e. above and outside of the function.

This now works. Thank you.

(not a fan of using composer. I understand the benefits but it's not needed for my small projects)

Comment: That’s good. Please mark this answer as correct!